# php get first node of object stdClass

Tags: php, parsing, paypal

I am working with the PayPal payment validation for the mobile SDKs.

Here is a dump of data that gets returned from the sandbox.

```
["proof_of_payment"]=>
object(stdClass)#27 (1) {
["adaptive_payment"]=>
object(stdClass)#28 (4) {
  ["app_id"]=>
  string(14) "APP-1234567890"
  ["payment_exec_status"]=>
  string(9) "COMPLETED"
  ["pay_key"]=>
  string(20) "AP-70M68096ML426802W"
  ["timestamp"]=>
  string(20) "2013-07-23T12:10:17Z"
```

so there is a "proof_of_payment" object, and within that there is an object called "adaptive_payment". Paypal says that as there are two types of payment they accept (credit card or paypal account) that the object within the proof_of_payment can be one of two things. "adaptive_payment" or "rest_api".

With PHP, how would you test for what is written in the space "adaptive_payment"? That is not your usual key->value case because it is the name of an object unto itself. Obviously array syntax won't work here because it is not an array, and nor can I do proof_of_payment[0]. So what is the proper way for testing for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check which key exists with [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset):

```
if (isset($obj->adaptive_payment)) {
  // adaptive payment code...
}
else if (isset($obj->rest_api)) {
  // rest api code...
}
```

Alternatively, you could use [`property_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php). But in your case, `isset()` is sufficient since the key will either be set or not set.